# Efficiently finding new max element in a set after removing some elements

Tags: c#, algorithm, optimization

We have some graphs (as in visual graphs with axes) with `n` data points, where `n` can be quite large. The data can be represented as coherent lists or arrays of x- and y-coordinates in double format, *and the x-values are sorted*. There may be duplicates among both the x- and y-values, and both may contain negative values. Furthermore, the y-values may contain values with `NaN`.

Each time the data are updated, we need to recalculate the max value of the y-values to update the max value on the axis of the graphs. This is easy if data points are inserted, since we can just compare the new value with the current max value and see if this is exceeded. But when removing data points, we need to check a lot more data.

Often, a range of values are removed, say from index `i` and the following `m` indices (we always receive this information as an index and a range in the data lists). Our current strategy is to find the max value of the removed `m` data points and compare this with the current max value for the entire data set. If one of these match, it is recalculated from the remaining `n - m` data points and updated. This means that we only rarely need to check against all `n` data points.

...but we would rather avoid this completely. The current remove operation has an average running time of O(1) (I think), but a worst-case of O(n). Is there some way to remove an element from a set and find the new max of the set in something like O(log n) which would be unnoticeable for our users? We can create and store additional lists and arrays of equivalent sizes if needed.

We have considered things like partitioning the data in segments, each with their own max value, but since the remove operation changes the indices of the underlying data, we need an efficient way of linking them without recalculating all indices. We also considered using a `SortedSet`, but sets don't allow duplicates.

I hope someone can point us to a solution or unexpectedly tell us that this method is already maximally efficient.

Comment: (To the close vote: I fail to see how this is opinion-based)

Comment: Are you redrawing the graph when the data is changed? If so, I would have thought that the drawing time would dwarf the time taken to recalculate the max Y value. (You presumably never need to explicitly find the max X value since your data is already sorted by X)

Comment: The drawing is handled very efficiently by the graph component itself, probably with some cheats like not drawing everything when there are millions of points etc. But we need to manually set the ranges on the axes as inputs to the graph. But you're right about the x-axis, we just snatch the first and last element there. I'll edit it out of the question for clarity.

Comment: What is *set*? Why finding maximum separately is a problem? What problem your data structure with always available maximum value is solving?

Comment: Your graph component will have to at least look at each data point once, I'd have thought. So even a quick O(n) across your entire range should be fairly cheap by comparison. A thought about partitioning into segments: you'll need to re-partition when new data comes in / is removed, but that partitioning can be done after you send the data to the graph component to draw, and so won't be on the critical path

Comment: Have you timed how long it takes to find the maximum Y value in an O(N) operation? I've just tried a basic loop to find the maximum value in an array of 10 million doubles, and it takes around 1/100th second on my PC (release build), so I'm wondering if you're just wasting your time.

Comment: @MatthewWatson We get results in the same range, so possibly. Right now, this method is only called a few times, but the worry is that it might be called say 10_000 times in a row for a segment of 10_000 data points with ascending data, so the max must be recalculated each time. But we might just set up some logic to group these calls or similar. We do have practical work-arounds but if this was a known problem with a simple solution, it would be cleaner and feel better.

Comment: If you were calling that 10K times in a row, I'd be more worried about redrawing the chart 10K times!

Comment: Of possible interest: https://thume.ca/2021/03/14/iforests/

Comment: @MatthewWatson Yes, I would too, but that is handled by the graph component which doesn't mind. It is a proprietary component, so I can't look under the hood to see what is going on there, but it probably queues update requests and uses some cheaty logic. It's not the bottleneck. We just need to find the max value.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat Thank you! I'll check that out and see if it is applicable.

Comment: If you're getting 10,000 updates in a row, I'd want to implement my own rate-limiting to limit how often I called into the graph component: I can't guarantee that it will always handle loads of fast updates in a row like that. Once you've done that, you've got an upper bound on how often you need to re-calculate the max